# Riddle Poem: These four require a detour

Tags: riddle

> Most in our family
>   Are born whole and quickly.
>
> But not us four
>   Who require a detour.
>
> We don't want to interrupt
>   Until the rest is developed.
>
> So until then we wait
>   To be put into our complete state.
>
> Then everything will make sense
>   When finished is the sequence.

Who are the "four" that this poem refers to?

Comment: I enjoy your riddles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is:

> the letters 'i', 't', 'j', and 'x'.  Letters you complete after you write a word in cursive (dot your i's and cross your t's!).

Comment: @Geobits you might wait till the end of a word... at least in cursive.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop You have the correct answer.  +1 to kbosak.

Comment: @pacoverflow  had to revise the 4th.. forgot my cursive! ;-)

Comment: I meant to say that you should edit your answer to specify the cursive lowercase letters 'i', 'j', 't', and 'x'.  Non-cursive letters are not a correct answer.

Comment: @pacoverflow - Why is 'x' on the list??

Comment: @randal'thor When you write a word such as "examine" in cursive, you can't finish the 'x' until after you've finished the word, right?

Comment: @pacoverflow - Not in my handwriting! I do curly 'x's that go (top left)->(bottom left)->(top right)->(bottom right). What sort of 'x' requires going back at the end? I'm curious :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Here is an example: http://www.studenthandouts.com/01-Web-Pages/2013-01-a/quick-brown-fox-cursive-script-handwritinng-practice.jpg

Answer (score 11):

Are the 4:

> Wisdom teeth

Most in our family
Are born whole and quickly.

> You normally have most of your teeth all at once.

But not us four
Who would require a detour.

> There are 4 teeth which come at some other unexpected time.

We don't want to interrupt
Until the rest is developed.

> They only come out AFTER the period of loosing baby-teeth has occurred.

So until then we wait
To be put into our complete state.

> Just poetic emphasis of the previous.

Then everything will make sense
When finished is the sequence.

> There is no further normal activity after the wisdom teeth have established themselves.

Comment: That's not what I had in mind.

Comment: @pacoverflow Oh good. That means it's not over so quickly

Answer (score 0):

this is my thought:

> Un-born quadruplets. two of them are fully developed in the womb, so they are waiting for the other two to develop so as not to interrupt their growth. As it is 4 children, a cesarean section will probably be used, which is a detour to the regular way of being born quickly.

i have no idea how i came up with this so quickly.

Comment: That's not what I had in mind.  I just added a couple lines.

Answer (score 0):

A tough one.. :)

Probably it's not so easy, but could it be

> the signs at the end of a sentence -> . ! ? ;

Comment: Building on this, what if it's not punctuation ending a sentence, but rather punctuation interrupting a sentence? - : ; ,

Comment: Second idea: could also be the paired punctuation marks: (), {}, [], ""